# Why wont my 360 controller recognise

Tags: 12.04, drivers, steam

Okay so I've done alot of trial and error on the subject of gaming on Ubuntu and Mint, all on fresh installs fully updated. Lately I installed the latest Ubuntu LTS 64 bit on my rig.

I installed all updates, my 32 bit libraries, Steam, and my amd graphics driver first off. Then I installed Team Fortress 2 on steam.  I've heard a lot of peoples controllers work right off the bat on steam but all of mine did not.

My controllers are as follows:

> -Blue Rock candy brand 360 controller
>
> -Official Microsoft Hard Wired 360 Controller
>
> -White PowerA brand Micro 360 controller

Okay so first its plugged in and it shows the first player light on like it should be working. All of them do this so that's good i assume as the driver at least detects it in someway as its not just blindly blinking. So I go into TF2 to see if it works. The options wont detect any input and when I bring up valve's console and exec 360controller everything says all joy buttons are not valid keys.  So I do some digging and ran across this [makeuseof.com](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/connect-your-xbox-360-controller-to-your-linux-gaming-rig/) page.

I used the command to see if it would list my pad anywhere but it said just usbcore driver no "led device" or "pad1" just nothing. I have tried both my USB 2.0 & 3.0 Ports
Obviously this is a driver problem of sorts Any help would be highly appreciated.

My Computer's Hardware is as follows:

> - Am3 AMD Phenom X4 965 3.4 CPU  * HIS Radeon HD 7750 PCI ex  * 2013 MSI 970A-G43 Mainboard  * 8GB DDR3 RAM Gskill Ripjaws  * 5.1 Diamond Extreme
>     sound pci sound card.

I will be digging into this issue as i have been this week in other words

What should I do ?

please :3 I will be quick to respond and will post things as I find them.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to connect with a XBox 360 wireless controller with a charger cord or directly with bluetooth? This won't work.

You will need to buy either a [Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming receiver for Windows](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-on-other-devices/connections/xbox-360-wireless-gaming-receiver-windows) or, if you want to have a wired controller, you need to buy [Xbox 360 Controller for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/xbox-360-controller-for-windows).

I own myself a Xbox 360 and have been trying the same thing like you did. This [article from Canonical](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Controller#line-22) guides you through the process.

Comment: That is very odd. I remember using one of them on mint to play ps1 games on mint with but that was back when i think Mint 14 was out.  I'm gonna try to see if my PC USB Raider (basically an advanced thrustmaster) will work and i will also try my homebrewed psp-1000 that has a usb controller program i put on it. I will report my findings. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Tried the pc Raider it didn't show up and i tried my psp 1000 & 2000 with fusa gamepad for pc it didn't show up so those two options are ruled out :/

Comment: Well i do know the black 360 controller i have was a microsoft pc/360 pad because my dad was stubborn and wanted to make sure it would work. And I just tried my Line 6 usb keyboard XD I use it in mint to produce music under reason 5 on wine. Unfortunately it didnt show up either.

Comment: You know whats crazy all of these are hardwired not charger wired so you figure all of them would work but i think the official is the only one that works so far.

Comment: I think some sources may be missing, I ran those commands on that page and i told me E: Unable to locate package jscalibrator
E: Unable to locate package libjsw2 and it couldnt locate xpad.ko i saved the terminal outcome for future reference.

Comment: `jscalibrator` and `libjsw2` are both outdated since some time. Since they are optional, skip this step. As for `xpad.ko` you will need to do the compiling stuff to get this file. You can skip compiling for 12.04 and 13.04 if you use the userspace drivers from the [linked page](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/). There is a PPA in there to use.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Black wired 360 controller to recognize on TF2! I waited till game loaded and plugged it in when i opened options :D. Don't know if this has anything to do with it but i plugged the controller into a 5 port usb extension i got from big lots a while back. I shall add if i make any more progress.